# Remove validation group from parent form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I use FOSUserBundle with a custom registration form that extends the one provided by the bundle. I want to override the validation so it doesn't check for a username (I generate it). I have read that this can be achieved thru the usage of validation groups.

These are the relevant parts of my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    ...

    $builder->remove('username');

    ...

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Ysu\Bundle\SiteBundle\Entity\User',
        'validation_groups' => array('my-registration-group'),
        'cascade_validation' => true
    ));
}

...
```

However the username is still validated with the validation files provided by the bundle. I found out that `$options` (array) contains an array `validation_groups`which in its turn contains the 'Registration' group, so that is why the field is still validated. However, I don't know how to remove it. If I unset it from `$options`before passing it to `parent::buildForm`it will still contain the `Registration` group.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can configure the validation groups for the FOSUserBundle's forms in config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    ....
    registration:
        form:
            validation_groups:  [default, registration_mod]
            ....
```